# Save a Excel File From API controller in AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, excel, download

I have tried to download a file from a method of my Web API Controller (Asp.net MVC 6). So, my file is created in a api controller and I want download my file, already in excel format, with angularjs. But, I don't know how to do.

Here is my method in my api controller: (it works, I already use this methods and class in an another project Asp.net without angularj)

```
#region downloadFile
[Route("Download")]
public ActionResult Download()
{
    string companyName = Context.Session.GetString("companyName") as string;
    string fileDownloadName =  Context.Session.GetString("fileDownloadName") as string;
    string baseFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\Temp");
    string folder = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseFolder, companyName);
    TempFile tempFile = new TempFile(folder, fileDownloadName);
    tempFile.FindFileInDirectory();
    return File(tempFile._pathDirectory + "\\"+tempFile._fileName, "Application/" + tempFile._fileExt, tempFile._fileName);

}
#endregion
```

This method returns an excel file. Now, I would download this file that is send in angularjs with a http request.

I have tried to use the method saveAs from fileSaver.js. I have added the js in my project but when I want use it, the method is always undefined.

```
 var requestDownloadFile = 
    $http({ 
        url: '/api/customers/Download'
        , responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        , headers: { 
            'contentType': 'application/json'
            , 'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' 
        } 
    });
    requestDownloadFile.success(function (data) {
        saveAs(data, 'test.xlsx');
});
```

I tried to use this too in my success method:

```
   var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-      officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" })
   var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(objectUrl);
```

It run a download file, but the file is corrupted.

So it's not realy effective because I have created a file in API and I have tried to recover an arrayBuffer but I'm blocked so I try.

All support is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, I complicated life. I just had to do this in the success:

```
  window.open('/api/customers/Download', '_blank', '');
  window.open('link/to/method/api', '_blank', '');
```