# AngularJS Save File From ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, download

I am returning a file from an ASP.NET MVC controller and I want to download it as an attachment using AngularJS.

MVC Controller:

```
return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
```

AngularJS:

```
function generatePDF(reportRequest) {

            var reportController = "Report";
            var controllerUrl = ngAppSettings.homeBaseUri + reportController + "/GeneratePDF";
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: controllerUrl,
                data: reportRequest
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
                //window.open(controllerUrl, "_self", "");
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (err, status) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });

            return deferred.promise;

        };
```

I've tried various ways as suggested on the similar questions about this but I'm not getting it.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307043/save-a-excel-file-from-api-controller-in-angularjs) too.

My breakpoints hit without any problems inside the GeneratePDF controller but nothing happens after that. How would I go about this?

EDIT:

I also tried [angular file saver](http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/) but I'm getting an error that the format should be in BLOB. If I can only convert the response to a blob then I think this might be it.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your C# Controller endpoint returns a FileContentResult (which it appears that it does), then you shouldn't need to worry about promises. You can simply do the following...

```
function generatePDF(reportRequest) {
            var reportController = "Report";
            var controllerUrl = ngAppSettings.homeBaseUri + reportController + "/GeneratePDF";
            window.open(controllerUrl, "_blank");
        };
```

I am doing this in one of my apps and it is working as expected. Is there a particular reason you were using the $q service to return a promise?

Comment: It's just the design of all my angular services uses $q service which I can ignore if this is an issue. Using window.open, how would I pass my reportRequest object as parameter for the GeneratePDF controller? I need it for data processing.

Comment: Ah sorry, overlooked that bit. Is there a lot of data in the reportRequest or is it something that could be represented in a "GET" query string (aka just basic primitives that you can make a query string out of)? Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to do a "POST" to download the doc. If you have to send a ton of data back to process in order to generate the pdf, you'll either need to do that and have the server pass back a token that you can then use to do a GET (using window.open) that will then return the FileResult that is cached on the server in some way.

Comment: I can't pass all the data as a query string as the request contains a list of objects. I was planning to do that too at first but didn't proceed.

Comment: Just to close this thread. Your comment pointed me to the right path and ended up making a POST to generate the document and a GET to download it.